# Filter data with standard derivation in loop

Tags: matlab

I have acceleration (10240x31) data that I want to filter by replacing every data point that exceeds the threshold value of 4 times standard derivation of each column with the mean value of the two adjacent data points.

First, I wanted to replace every data point with a zero, if it exceeds the maximum value. This is my loop:

```
for w = 1:31
    Sigma(w) = std(zacceleration(:,w));
    zacceleration(zacceleration<(-4*Sigma(w))) = 0;
    zacceleration(zacceleration>(4*Sigma(w))) = 0;
end
```

That code works if w is just one number, for example:

```
w = 1;
```

But when w changes every iteration, the filtered data only contains the values that don't exceed the threshold value of the last dataset, Sigma(31).
So, I guess that I overwrite my data or something like that but I cant seem to find a solution.

Can anybody please give me a hint?

Thank you in advance and best regards.

Comment: What if you have two consecutive data points that exceed that range? Also it may be worth just using a median filter to remove the spikes.

Comment: I have not thought about that because this never has never happened. Thanks for the advice. What do you mean by using a median filter? I still want to have all my data points, I do not want to merge them.

Comment: A median filter is meant to remove impulse noise like you've described https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/medfilt1.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this is what I want. It alters my data too much.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it now.

```
Sigma = std(zacceleration);
for  a = 1:10240;
    for b = 1:31;
        if zacceleration(a,b)<(-4*Sigma(b))
            zacceleration(a,b) = 0;
        end
        if zacceleration(a,b)>(4*Sigma(b))
            zacceleration(a,b) = 0;
        end
    end
end
```